# confusing coordinate system on storyboard xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, coordinate

I'm trying to make my image view that i put in Xcode right at 0, 0 top right corner with 320 460 so it spans over entire screen, in the size inspector i made sure to have the origin with the red arrows right at the top left so its the right coordinate thing, but for some reason when i put the image view in the exact center its telling me that the center is 20x 160 y
why is it doing this, when i click on my view its saying the center is 0x 0y the way is supposed to be, this is making me mad

Comment: now when i just moved the image into another view its now telling me the origin is 20 90

Comment: o i think it might have something to do with my scroll view

Comment: Just an fyi, wait more than 10 minutes before you start demanding answers so you dont hulk out. It actually almost made me stop attempting to help.

Comment: Oops, I came to this question years after and saw some comments I didn't like and deleted them. But after I did that I realized ColdLogic's comment made no more sense, and I couldn't restore the comments. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im not sure what you mean by "when i put the image view in the exact center", but regardless if you use the size inspector, and set the origin to (0,0) with a size of (320,460), it will span the entire view.

Beyond that, the view you are loading the image view into needs to be origined at (0,0) and with a size of (320,460).

It sounds like the views you are putting the image view into are not positioned correctly, as the coordinate system is in relation to the parent view.